# Multiple api call

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client, yelp-fusion-api

I'm trying to build a nodejs app that runs and if statement to query multiple api's to return a result.  Example, running yelps api first, if it finds then break, else continue query another api such as google places or white pages api until it finds a result.

I am passing in either a name of a business, address to return a telephone number. the results expected are in json.  I am drawing a blank.

ideas?

Comment: try to be more elaborative with the question and please provide some code so that we can help.. this seems to be a problem of your call .. but can't say anything until we see some codes

Comment: I’m more so stuck on how to begin writing the call.  I want to do three api calls but exit when it finds the right quartz. Any ideas as to how to begin or anywhere you can point me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the way to achieve this is you should be able to make http req from your server side and when a result comes with a response then you should check that response. If your requested answer is not in it then you should keep on trying other API end points untill u come across with a suitable response..

so here are some npm packages to achieve this simply

- http - node js built in package
- Axios - [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)
- request - [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

try using one of these packages .. I would use axios .. read their doc and try to do it .. It should clear somethings out for you

Comment: this is perfect, with axios, can you pass in api keys?

Comment: if u r satisfied with the answer please vote and mark it as the answer .. :)

Comment: what do you mean API keys ? u mean for google  and white pages api keys ? if so then you should create accounts in google ( I think u already have one and then you will need to register with white pages and then get api key generated for you

Comment: Yes i have the api keys already, what i meant is, is there a method in axios to pass in the api keys as parameters?

Comment: that depends on the api u are using mate .. so if the API requests your key to be added to your req header then you can do it .. there is a way in axios read the docs. but most cases APIs require API keys to be binded with the req as a parameter so its easy like this www.api.com/v1/api/getData/key=hshdfzwej093urhrlurfhrgrg .....

like wise concatenate to the req  just like above